# Writing custom php script in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I am good in php and javascript. I need a guidance where to place my custom php script if i make a ajax call from joomla.

I need to fetch the file names from a specific folder. I could make an ajax that will communicate with my php code and in return, my php code will give me the files of the specific folder.

Where is that php script to be place and how it should be routed.

For example

```
$.ajax({

url:'....../fetchfiles.php',
success:function(data){

}

})
```

Hope i was clear.

Comment: Does the Joomla website in question have a custom component or module you could leverage?

Comment: I am free to do anything. I can go for a custom component install if required.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly your question my answer would be that you can place your fetchfiles.php wherever you want providing that you put right path to the file in your $.ajax call.

Then in the fetches.php you should call Joomla framework before you start your code, something like this:

```
// no direct access 
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

// get joomla root
$jpath_root = $_POST['jpath_root'];

//load Joomla
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $jpath_root );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

jimport( 'joomla.application.application' );
jimport( 'joomla.filter.filteroutput' );

$japp = JFactory::getApplication('site');

/* now you are good to go with your code */
```

Just a few words about

```
// get joomla root
$jpath_root = $_POST['jpath_root'];
```

part.

My experience is that it is the best if you pass JPATH_ROOT variable via $.ajax( one way would be to have hidden input with value set to 'JPATH_ROOT' in your joomla file from where you call ajax and then in your ajax.js just pick that value up and pass to the ajax.php or fetches.php in your case)

You can define JPATH_BASE another way too, eg

```
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

or

```
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' ));
```

depending on your actual files structure but be aware that this way you practically redefined original JPATH_BASE constant and that it may cause conflicts in case you call, later within your code, some third party component functions/classes which may depend on original Joomla defined constants ...

I've learned it hard way with ZOO Component and my ajax calls ... :)

Hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on where you want to show the results you can create a component or a module (you can also easily include the module in an article to print the result in component position).

In the case of module:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module
Obviously your ajax call will be in `tmpl/default.php` and your php script in the module folder, simply you have to include it in the file list in `mod_helloworld.xml`. Then zip your folder and install it using Module Manager.

In case of problem with your jquery code, you have to use the [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode.